# Why is the engineering chatroom so quiet

Tags: discussion, chat, stackexchange

Why is the engineering chatroom so quiet and there are no moderators to the rescue?Electrical engineering has a separate chatroom but there isn't one for mechanical engineers.Moderators please create one at the earliest.Please make Mechanical chatroom wide enough for physical metallurgy and extraction questions to fit in.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not certain that I'm following the basis of your question.

Chat rooms live or die based upon the community that springs up within them.  Engineering.SE has "The Skunk Works" as its room, other SE sites have their own.  Pretty much anything Engineering related is on-topic for "The Skunk Works."

If you would like to see it be more active, then you need to be pro-active and provide meaningful commentary within there.  I have seen the rise and fall of other rooms (notably, "The Whiteboard") and it all comes down to the community of active participants.  That's not anything a moderator has control over.

The Electrical chat room is tied to the Electronics.SE site.  There's a subtle distinction there in scope.  The Electronics site has been around for quite a bit longer and has a more established user base.

If we need a separate room for mechanical questions, any chat user with sufficient reputation can create one.  But there's plenty of room within "The Skunk Works" for those types of questions right now.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Engineering might be a forum with sporadic but not passionate, regular but not high-volume visitors.  There is math and physics behind the answer, right?

That is more about "how" driving a short frontier "why".

It might be over-regulated.  It might be uninteresting to enough of the folks who come.  It might have trolls.  Perhaps it is new, or under-known?

Comment: That's a very verbose way to say *"I don't know"*.